# JQuery + Bind event for all the elements except a certain div and its all elements

Tags: jquery

I need to bind mouseover, mouseout and click events for the all the elements but except a certain Div and it's child elements.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <!-- page content goes here -->
        </div>
        <div class="popup">Popup content goes here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can bind the events for all the elements as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).find("body *").mouseover(function(e){
        // do something
    }).mouseout(function(e){
        // do something
    }).click(function(e){
        // do something
    });
});
```

I tried in several ways to ignore the content of ".popup" div. But it wasn't successful.

Appreciate your solution. Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to do... do you want to bind the event to all elements? then how do you handle propagation etc

Comment: Hi @ArunPJohny, yes i need to bind the event for all elements expect a specified element and its all children. Here i need to stop the current propagation, so that I use `e.stopPropagation();`. Thanks!

Comment: Hi All, I managed to solve it as below. `$(this).find("body *").filter(function(  ) { return !($(this).parents().index($('.popup')) != -1 ||  $(this).hasClass('popup') ); }) .mouseover(function(e){})`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find("body *").not(".popup").mouseover(function(e){
        // do something
    }).mouseout(function(e){
        // do something
    }).click(function(e){
        // do something
    });
```

**but you must try below code in document reday** `$(this)` **not work**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body *").not(".popup").mouseover(function(e){
            // do something
        }).mouseout(function(e){
            // do something
        }).click(function(e){
            // do something
        });
});
```

reference **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**

Comment: Hi Rituraj, `$("body *").not(".popup")` works only for the elements which has got 'popup' calss. but in my case, i need it to be worked for its children too.

Comment: @rituraj-ratan Is it possible to do same thing using javascript or angular? What is the equivalent of this?

Comment: for this in comment see http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/this-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).find("body *").not(':has(> .yourclassyoudontwant)').mouseover(function(e){
        // do something
    }).mouseout(function(e){
        // do something
    }).click(function(e){
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @user3035456, `$("body *").not(':has(> .popup)')` is not working anyway. but `$("body *").not('.popup')` works only for the elements which has got 'popup' class. but in my case, i need it to be worked for its children too.

Comment: how about:

$("body *").not('.popup *') or $("body *").not('.popup').children()